# Where is Source Code for Microsoft Power Platform Connectors and Providers?

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, power-platform

I am trying to better understand the parameters for Power Platform Actions associated with Connectors. I would like to look at the source code associated with Microsoft provided Connectors.

There is a GitHub repo for [Microsoft Certified Connects](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerPlatformConnectors/tree/dev/certified-connectors) from third parties but I could not find a similar repo for Microsoft own Connectors. :(

Answer (score 0):

[Building an ecosystem of open source connectors](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/building-an-ecosystem-of-open-source-connectors/) - Though the announcement was made and some partners made some of them open source in github, I think not many of them made it so.

The native connectors were classified into standard and premium, and they were not made open source by MS. Only the custom connectors (samples mostly) and certified connectors in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerPlatformConnectors) are available for community contribution.